# UV artefacts when importing to Keyshot

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I have strange problem (probably I'm just too newbie) when importing blender model with engraving to keyshot.

Engraved logo doesn't appear correctly in keyshot.

[image]

[image]

Blend file:
[image]

Comment: It looks like this is caused by keyshot's lack of support for n-gons. Perhaps adding some edges across the n-sided faces or triangulating the mesh would fix the issue.

Comment: @HISEROD thank you for suggestion, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

### *Solution to this problem:*

**1.**   [image]

**2.**
Select all edges along top and bottom face of an engraved part and bevel those
[image]

***.**
If you want to avoid strange reflections (on faces within the hole) when applying texture to blender model in keyshot, I recommend to bevel edges of a hole as well.

*Model before beveling:*
[image]

*Model after beveling:*
[image]

Hope this will help someone in the future. Thanks to HISEROD for the right direction.